# How to solve $3\sin^3x-5\sin x\cos x+2\cos^2 x=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

Solve $3\sin^3x-5\sin x\cos x+2\cos^2 x=0$.
It should use simple identities, but no identity I used helped me. There has to be a trick but I don't seem to find it. I could really use any kind of help.

Comment: Are you sure you have cubic and not a quadratic? Since you can see $\sin x=\cos x$ solves the latter.

Comment: @Chinny84, you are mis/applying polya's  dictum that if you cant solve a problem, find a problem that you can solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is way to solve the equation $$3\sin^3t-5\sin t\cos t+2\cos^2 t=0 $$ we will introduce $$x = \cos t, y = \sin t, x^2 + y^2 = 1\tag 1$$ now we have 
$$0=3y^3 - 5xy + 2x^2 = 3y(1-x^2)-5xy+2x^2=-y(3x^2+5x-3)+2x^2 .$$ soving for $y$ gives $$y= \frac{2x^2}{3x^2 + 5x-3}\tag 2 $$

the graphs of $(1)$ and $(2)$ intersect at four points in the first, third and fourth quadrants. the coordinates are  $$x = 0.912, 0.563, 0.937, 0.418.$$ the corresponding angles in radians are $$0.422, 0.9727,3.498, 5.144 $$

Comment: In response to your comment above.. I am indeed going with the solution with least resistance ;). +1 for solving the stated problem and for teaching me a new concept word!!

Comment: @Chinny84, good to see you back.

Comment: It's always nice to have a welcome back!!

Answer (score 1):

convert this equation in $\tan(x/2)$ and set $t=\tan(x/2)$
$$24\,{\frac { \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{3}}{ \left( 1+
 \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{3}}}-10\,{
\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \left( 1- \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) }{ \left( 1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{2}}}+2\,{\frac { \left( 1- \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{2}}}=0
$$

Comment: How did you convert sine to tangent? 
Can you show the sequence of events for $\sin x$?
I try but it wouldn't work well. I would really appreciate it .

Comment: Is this easier to solve?

Comment: use that $$2\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
=\sin(x)$$ and

Comment: $${\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}
=\cos(x)$$

Comment: i think this method works also in each case

Comment: I know this is what I were to use, except I didn't have this identity, and I wanted to know how it is achieved.

Comment: plugging this in the given equation